# how to create a new class instance object dynamically

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I have a class

```dart
    class Account extends Stuff{
      String name;
      newObject(){
        return new Account();
      }
    }
```

inside the Stuff class I have a method

```dart
    //generates list of objects of the same type 
    //as given object and fills attribute 
    generateObjectsFromExisting(names)
      {
        List list = new List();
        InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflect(this);
        Symbol formatSymbol = new Symbol("newObject");
        for(var name in names){
          //calles newObject function from this and returns a new object
          var newInstanceObject = instanceMirror.invoke(formatSymbol, []);
          Symbol symbol = new Symbol("name");
          InstanceMirror field = newInstanceObject.setField(symbol,name);
          list.add(newInstanceObject.reflectee)
        }
        return list;
      }
```

so when writing

```dart
    main(){
      var account = new Account();
      List accounts = new List();
      accounts = account.generateObjectsFromExisting(['tim','tom']);
      print(account.name) // returns null
      print(accounts[0].name) // returns tim
      print(accounts[1].name) // returns tom
    }
```

the problems with this way are

1 'generateObjectsFromExisting()' is on the 'account' object and not on Account

2 I have to manually add the "newObject" Method to every single class I implement.

I would prefer a static Method like 'Account.generateObjectsFromExisting()' 
but how to to access 'this' (since its not available in static) 
so I can say "this.new()" or something equivalent to "new Account();" eg "new this();"
and therefor be able to only have one 'newObject' function inside Stuff or maybe wont need it at all.

so now my code would look like this

```dart
    class Account extends Stuff{
      String name;
    }
```

in Stuff

```dart
    static generateObjectsFromExisting(names)
      {
        List list = new List();
        for(var name in names){
          var object = new this();
          object.name = name;
          list.add(object)
        }
        return list;
      }
```

in main

```dart
    main(){
      // returns list of Accounts filled with names
      accounts = Account.generateObjectsFromExisting(['tim','tom']);
      print(accounts[0].name) // returns tim
      print(accounts[1].name) // returns tom
    }
```

if you can show me a way to access the Class to do something like this.new(); or new this(); then obviously the class 'Account' needs to be accessed and not the extended 'Stuff'

if the 'this' approach is not possible, then maybe you can show me a way how to access the Class from within an already existing object

like

```dart
    generateObjectsFromExisting(names)
      {
        List list = new List();
        var class = this.class;
        var newObject = class.new():
        ...          
      }
```

or is my current approach the only solution. .. hope not  :)

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of at the moment. But both of them are pretty close to your initial solution as they both use reflection..

The non-static solution:

```dart
class Stuff {

  generateObjectsFromExisting(List<String> names) {
    var cm = reflectClass(this.runtimeType);
    return names.map((name) {
      var newInstance = cm.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
      newInstance.name = name;
      return newInstance;
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

The static solution:

```dart
class Stuff {

  static generateObjectsFromExisting(type, List<String> names) {
    var cm = reflectClass(type);
    return names.map((name) {
      var newInstance = cm.newInstance(const Symbol(''), []).reflectee;
      newInstance.name = name;
      return newInstance;
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

You would call the static solution like this:

```dart
var accounts = Stuff.generateObjectsFromExisting(Account, ['tim', 'tom']);
```

There might be another solution involving factory constructors but can't think of any right now. Also, this code would easily break when you get another subclass of `Stuff` that does not have a `name` attribute. I don't know if you really intended on putting that attribute on `Account` instead of `Stuff`.

Also answering you 'Class'-Question. There is no class in Dart, there is only the `Type` and to get it you can do:

```dart
Type type1 = Account;
Type type2 = account.runtimeType;
```

But the Type doesn't have any methods you could use to create a new instance.

Comment: the 'name' attr was just an example ;) in my real case I set them dynamically. 

cool reflectClass(type); answers few of my questions 
:D normally I don't hesitate to surf through the api. 

so inside your/a static method, is there a way to get the type Stuff without passing it down, or better is there an equivalent to this?

Comment: Since it's static and you don't want to pass any reference about the type (and you said you want type Stuff), you can just pass type Stuff to `reflectClass`, like `var cm = reflectClass(Stuff)`. The problem is you can only create an instance with its Type is Stuff. The best approach is using non-static method, like @KayZ posted above.

Comment: so there is no equivalent of 'this' in 'static'?

Comment: Correct. Even if it were, you wouldn't be able to call your static function on `Account`, because it's only defined on `Stuff` and static functions are not inherited.